# Overriding add method for list to check if an attribute equals another instances attribute

Tags: java, oop, equals

!!!Only for practice!!!

Car is a immutable object which has attributes `String owner, String registration....`

So here is my code MyGarage implements Garage which contains a method add.

MyGarage also has a ArrayList which accepts a argument of type Car

The method is suppose to check if the car is all ready in the list by identifying the registration

Car

```
final class Car{
    private String owner;
    private final String registration;
    private final String make;
    private final int kilometres;
    private final double price;

    public Car(String ownerString, String registrationString, String makeString, int kilometresInt, double priceDouble){
        owner = ownerString;
        registration = registrationString;
        make = makeString;
        kilometres = kilometresInt;
        price = priceDouble;
    }

    public String getOwner(){
        return owner;
    }

    public String getRegistration(){
        return registration;
    }

    public String getMake(){
        return make;
    }

    public int getkilometres(){
        return kilometres;
    }

    public double getprice(){
        return price;
    }



}
```

MyGarage

The method add is compareing if ti is not equal to null store it, how can I set this to `if()` the registration is already in the list do not add else add

```
   import java.util.ArrayList;



public class MyGarage implements Garage {

    private ArrayList<Car> myGarage;

    public MyGarage() {
        myGarage = new ArrayList<Car>();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(Car c) {
        for(Car car : myGarage) {

            //This is where I make the ceck I am not sure how and I know this is only checking to make sure 
            //the value does not equal null not if it is the same registration
            if(getCar(car.getRegistration())!=null) {           



                System.out.println("Car has the same Registration as another illegal");
                return false;       
            }   
        }
        myGarage.add(new Car(c.getOwner(),c.getRegistration(),c.getMake(),c.getkilometres(), c.getprice()));
        return true;
    }
}
```

Test Class

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyGarage garage = new MyGarage();

        garage.add(new Car("Tom", "222","Honda",  1, 1000.99));
        garage.add(new Car("Sam", "333","Honda",  2, 2000.99));
        garage.add(new Car("Bob", "444","Ford",  3, 3000.99));
        garage.add(new Car("Bob", "444","Ford",  3, 3000.99));

        garage.display();   
    }

}
```

}

This will display all 4 Car objects in the list the 4th instance should not be allowed in the list

Comment: Sounds like you may want a Map instead of a list, with the registration String as the key. If the order matters you could use LinkedHashMap or TreeMap.

Comment: @ boot-and-bone: Thanks, would I use a `HashMap` if the order does not matter?

Comment: That's the most common general map. And for any map `values()` returns a collection of just the values.